# Drupal .Htaccess file with URL RewriteRule

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new to drupal and how it's functions work, but I am trying to adjust the .htaccess file to adjust some old urls to create some better SEO friendly ones.

I know Drupal has a clean URL writter which is fine, but i'm trying to forward some old urls. Here is an example of the URL structure.

Current OLD url
**http://www.example.com/own**

Switch to the new URL
**http://www.example.com/own-real-estate/own-123**

So within my .htaccess file in the ROOT of the website (/html/)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  #THIS
  RewriteRule ^/own-real-estate/own-123(.*)$ http://www.example.com/own [R=301,L]

  #OR THIS
  RewriteRule http://www.example.com/own-real-estate/own-123(.*)$ http://www.example.com/own [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Or is there a CACHING problem that is causing problems? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wrote your rule backwards

```
RewriteRule ^/own http://www.example.com/own-real-estate/own-123 [R=301,L,NC]
```

This guide will give you a quick primer on .htaccess url rewriting
http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php